# Why doesn't python's email parser find all parts of this multipart MIME email?

Tags: python, email, parsing, mime, multipart

I am attempting to work with a simple multipart MIME email using Python's [email module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html). However, for some reason I do not understand, I cannot walk all the parts of the email - the application/pdf gets left out of the walk, for some reason.

Sample failing operation:

```
import email    

msgstring = '''See bottom of post'''

msg = email.message_from_string(msgstring)

has_pdf_attached = False

for part in msg.walk():
    print (part.get_content_type())
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/pdf':
        payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        if '%PDF-' in payload:
            has_pdf_attached = True

print(has_pdf_attached)
```

Output (notice that the final 'application/pdf' part is absent from the `print`ing of parts):

```
multipart/alternative
text/plain
text/html
False
```

Message itself, snipped up to show important bits:

```
--_=_swift_v4_145618772756cba94f8fcc2_=_
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------=_1456187728-18401-69"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

------------=_1456187728-18401-69
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

A bunch of content here
foobar
barfoo
etc

------------=_1456187728-18401-69
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body>
    <p>HTML version of content</p>
</body></html>

------------=_1456187728-18401-69--

--_=_swift_v4_145618772756cba94f8fcc2_=_
Content-Type: application/pdf; name test.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename test.pdf

A_Big_Long_Base64_Enconded_PDF_File_foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
JVBER0OUMyNzc0ODFDODAwMTI+IF0KL0RvY0NoZWNrFADSFsfsaFdsafsdaf
dHhyZWYKMzE4MjkKJSVFT0YKFDSFDSFdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds

--_=_swift_v4_145618772756cba94f8fcc2_=_--
```

So what am I doing wrong? I notice that the "detected" parts are all in the first 'section' wrapped by the mysterious-to-me `--_=_swift_v4_145618772756cba94f8fcc2_=_--`. I assume that is related, but google and SO searches failed, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard Stack Overflow experience, all I had to do was ask the question publicly and then the simple answer would manifest before my eyes.

My `msgstring` did not contain the entire original email - the IMAP library I used was misconfigured and was lopping off the message's main header. `--_=_swift_v4_145618772756cba94f8fcc2_=_` is indeed a boundary - the main boundary of the entire multipart message.

When I fed the actual complete message in as `msgstring`, it worked like a charm.

Chalk this silly question up to not knowing MIME format very well.